# Cannot tile the "Files" window to the left or right side by pressing Super + Left/Right keys very often

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, multiple-monitors, window-manager

Environment:

Hardware: A laptop and a standalone monitor connected;

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I'm very fond of the function to tile windows by side (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-tiled.html.en), but there are something wrong with it on my computer.

Object: The **"Files"** window. I tried a lot of applications/windows, the tiling shortcuts work fine on all of them but only the "Files" window.

I open the **"Files"** window, press the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> keys, nothing happened, and neither does <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> but I can maximize and restore the window by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> and I can also switch the windows between my two monitors by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

For other applications/windows, the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right/Up/Down</kbd> all work fine.

BTW, the related settings in **Settings - Devices - Keyboard** are all correct.

I tried to turn on/off or change some related settings, nothing worked.

At the end I found one way to make the shortcut keys come into effect by dragging the window **by the mouse**, move it to the left or right side of the standalone monitor until the semi-transparent tiling indication appears, then I can tile the **"Files"** window to the left/right side of both the laptop monitor or the standalone monitor **by <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcut keys**.

After I close the **"Files"** window and reopen it, the problem comes again. Drag to tile, the problem is "fixed" again.

**[UPDATE]**

I just find another way to "fix" this problem by setting the standalone monitor as the primary display. In this case, I can directly tile the "Files" window by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> normally. But I don't prefer this awkward display settings.

Comment: No buddy else comes into similar case? I don't know if this is a general bug or else?

Comment: Now I set the standalone monitor as the primary display as a workaround, but I still wish to have this problem fixed and I strongly want to know the cause behind. Anyone have any related guess which may work can also point out for me to test.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a rather strange work-around.
Click on the 'Files' application and switch off the 'Sidebar' setting.
The windows then work correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll try when back home. feedback would be a bit late.

Comment: It works, but the sidebar is 100% necessary. Nautilus sucks.

Comment: Santropedro - I wouldn't say Nautilus sucks.

Comment: My work-around was 1/2 aimed at users & 1/2 aimed at those trying to make it better. For users, switching sidebar off, re-arranging windows then switching sidebar on again works. For developers why this happens has to be a big clue as to what's wrong.